# Xamarin.Forms Item Detail page with Grid, Listview

Tags: xamarin.forms

Given the below Item details page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.Views.ItemDetailPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    <ScrollView>

    <StackLayout Spacing="2" Padding="15">
        <Label Text="Date:" FontSize="Small"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Item.Date}" FontSize="Small" />
        <Label Text="School:" FontSize="Small"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Item.School}" FontSize="Small"/>
        <Label Text="Description:" FontSize="Small"  FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Item.Description}" FontSize="Small"/>
        <Label Text="Condition:" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Item.Condition}" FontSize="Small"/>
        <Label Text="Offnormal:" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Item.Offnormal}" FontSize="Small"/>
        <Label Text="EventType:" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Item.EventType}" FontSize="Small"/>
        <Label Text="BaseState:" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Item.BaseState}" FontSize="Small"/>
        <Label Text="Code:" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Item.Code}" FontSize="Small"/>
        <Label Text="Account:" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Item.Account}" FontSize="Small"/>
        <Label Text="RestoreFor:" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Item.RestoreFor}" FontSize="Small"/>
    </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

How do I display in a grid or listview?
When i've tried using the same/similar code for the Listview / Grid that sends the SelectedItem property to this details page I get a blank page other than the title.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Item is an your listview model right? If it correct remove "Item" from binding object. You can achieve like this  <Label Text="{Binding School}" FontSize="Small"/>

Comment: Update your question with the expected design to show data

Comment: "When i've tried" - then show us what you've tried so we can help you fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. To be clear my issue was sending the SelectedItem and worked fine for Label binding, but ListView ItemsSource requires a List. I changed that accordingly and the following works:

```
<ScrollView>
    <!--Spacing="2" Padding="15">-->
    <StackLayout >
        <Label Text="Date:" FontSize="Small"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Item[0].Date}" FontSize="Small" />

        <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView2"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Item}"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            HasUnevenRows="true"
            IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid BackgroundColor="White" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text ="{Binding Date}" HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"></Label>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[Here's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7GA0.gif)